# How to hide stripe key via .env

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, stripe-payments

How can I hide the stripe secret key with .env?

on the real code it's write like this in Server.js file:
`const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");`

I tried to do something like this:
 `const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_KEY);`

and the secret key is on .env file(STRIPE_KEY=sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX), but it doesn't work...

Comment: did you use the `dotenv` package?

Comment: `.env`  is not meant for production . what server do you have?

Comment: @AlanOmar - really? what do you do in production?

Comment: Yes sure I use dotenv package, for the key of the mongoose it works but not for the stripe...

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction?